# Rearrange JSON multi-level array

Tags: angularjs, json

I receive a Json array from web service. This array contains others arrays.
How can I transform this structure to a one-level array to create a HTML table?

For instance, given this structure,

```
[
   {
      "uuid": "3f3f363d-322",
      "name": "xxx",
      "pay":[
         {
          "uuid": "123",
          "number": "9791070",
          },
          {
          "uuid": "124",
          "number": "9791071",
          }
      ]
    }
]
```

... I want to change to this structure:

```
[
   {
       "uuid": "3f3f363d-322",
       "name": "xxx",
       "pay":
          {
          "uuid": "123",
          "number": "9791070",
          }
   },
   {
       "uuid": "3f3f363d-322",
       "name": "xxx",
       "pay":
          {
          "uuid": "124",
          "number": "9791071",
          }
   }
]
```

I tried to use ng-repeat and ng-if like this :

```
<tr ng-repeat="entry in entries >
  <div ng-if="entry.pay.length>1">
     <div ng-repeat=item in entry.pay">
        <td>entry.uuid</td>
        <td>pay.number</td>
     </div>
  </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can repeat `<tbody>` and within each `<tbody>` repeat `<tr>`.

Your html is invalid since `<div>` can't be child of `<tr>` or parent of `<td>`

```
<tbody ng-repeat="entry in entries"  ng-if="entry.pay.length" >
     <tr ng-repeat="item in entry.pay">
        <td>entry.uuid</td>
        <td>pay.number</td>
     </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

except for some typos and missing braces your idea is correct, try:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in entries >
  <div ng-if="entry.pay.length>1">
     <div ng-repeat="item in entry.pay">
        <span>{{entry.uuid}}</span>
        <span>{{item.number}}</span>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Furthermore its worth mentioning as said before that your html is invalid

Comment: except it's invalid html

Comment: I forgot to add "pay" can be empty : 'pay':[]

Comment: That doesnt matter. If its empty ng repeat will not create any entries. The current Version only shows arrays with at least 2 entries (>1)